# Медленно в Access, быстро в SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Процедура установлена в качестве `RecordSource` формы. При открытии формы осуществляется её вызов и по прошествии таймаута прекращается, оставив форму пустой.
Вызываю на сервере - процедура выполняется за ~2 секунды, возвращает набор записей. 
Смотрел через профайлер - вызовы внешне идентичны, однако `Reads` при вызове с клиента > 28 млн, а с сервера ~70 тыс. Похоже, что в первом случае идёт обычное сканирование всех записей и, т.к. записей очень много, выборка не укладывается в таймаут. Индексы есть. Не могу разобраться в чём тут дело.

Скриншот профайлера

http://take.ms/u7tTy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось. Простое решение - изменить

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc]  
        @param1 int,  
 AS  
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = @param1
```

на

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc] 
    @param1 int,
AS
DECLARE @param1a int
SET @param1a = @param1
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = @param1a
```

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13823047/4269118)

Но проблема более глубока и связана с особенностями ADO и SQL Server. Изучить её можно [тут](http://www.somewheresomehow.ru/fast-in-ssms-slow-in-app-part1/).